# HTTP GET script based on httplib

Tags: python

I need a tool, which can download some part of data from web server, and after that i want connection not be closed. Therfore, i thought about a script in python, which can do:
1) send request
2) read some part of response
3) will freeze - server should think that connection exist, and should not close it

is it possilbe to do it in python ? here is my code:

```
conn = HTTPConnection("myhost", 10000)
conn.request("GET", "/?file=myfile")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason
data = r1.read(2000000)
print len(data)
```

When im running it, all data is received, and after that server closes connection.

thx in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

`httplib` doesn't support that. Use another library, like [`httplib2`](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/). Here's [example](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/02/01/doing-http-caching-right-introducing-httplib2.html).